# How to pass props and activate function on same onclick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to receive a prop and activate the function using the same onclick.

In navbar.js passed props
`<Hamburger menuOpen={this.ToggleMenu} />`

In Hamburger.js received props. Currently, this.handleClicks function activates, but no props functionality. If I switch their places, props functionality would work but function won't work.

```
handleClick = () => {
 console.log('handle click');
};

<div
 className={classes.Start}
 onClick={(this.props.menuOpen, this.handleClick)}
 >
This is div.
</div>
```

Comment: @sheikhhamza what is not clear can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to achieve is to call this.props.menuOpen inside your onClick handler.

```
handleClick = () => {
 console.log('handle click');
 this.props.menuOpen();
};

<div
 className={classes.Start}
 onClick={this.handleClick}
 >
This is div.
</div>
```

Assigning multiple functions to the onClick handler like you've done does not work.

Comment: In function adding this.props.menuOpen(); would crash the application with error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Comment: What is your in your ToggleMenu function inside your Hamburger component?

Comment: Great, glad to help.